# Wiring a SNES Controller to pi3 gpio or tactile switches

Tags: pi-3, wiring, switches

I'm looking to build a super pi boy, in the original they use tactile switches. However, I'm not sure how to wire the tactile switches and make them work as a x b y up down left right etc. I'm also looking into cutting up this controller's pcb board https://www.adafruit.com/product/131 like in the super game pi but, would I need an adapter for the snes controller connections? Like the cupcade pcb adapter or other controller adapters. My last option would be to switch over to building a pigrrl 2.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of building your own controller using tactile switches, you can cheaply buy a USB SNES controller. That's what I have done for my retro-pi setup. You can buy a kit that comes with controller PCB and case.

As you can see below, the buttons are rubber contact based and not tactile.

[image]

Here is a [deal from Walmart](https://www.walmart.com/ip/TSV-2-Packs-SNES-USB-Controller-For-PC-Mac-Super-Nintendo-Games-Retro-Classic-Gamepad/302369441?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=2961&adid=22222222227133991700&wl0=&wl1=s&wl2=c&wl3=242052865572&wl4=pla-395682833986&wl5=9032144&wl6=&wl7=&wl8=&wl9=pla&wl10=113509951&wl11=online&wl12=302369441&wl13=&veh=sem), 2 controllers for $10 + Free shipping.

[image: snes controller]

Overall, tactile switches are not used in mainstream controllers from PS4, Xbox, SNES, NES, any Nintendo, etc. These mainstream controllers use soft switches / buttons with rubber pads.

If you are too inclined to build your own controller, then try to find some non-tactile switches. I'll try to improve this answer if I can find some good switches.